# "Anonymous" throttling in wso02 api manager?

Tags: wso2

We're looking to replace an existing API manager with wso2 and one of the features of the other platform is that we can identify a 'user' of the API at run time and have the throttling work.

The 'user' is not OAuth identified, rather they authenticate via the API and a session id is returned (so they've never registered at a 'store'). This session id is then used to setup the throttling at the API Manager. Additionally the other tool has code to look for the user logging in and using that id in the throttling. so if a user tries to login too many times per hour the API manager blocks the request in addition to too many requests for a logged in user per hour. The combinations of login attempts, API calls etc. are summed into the throttle. (All this was implemented by their services team years ago)

The main reason we need this is we don't want to force our old clients to go to OAuth immediately but want much more visibility, reporting and throttling.

Thoughts on how to do this with wso2? I see where we can add our own Handlers to the API to figure out session ids, login ids etc. but I don't see where to create the logic to do the throttling.

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Login to Carbon and edit the tiers.xml (`/_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/tiers.xml`)。You can found the section  `<throttle:ID throttle:type="ROLE">Unauthenticated</throttle:ID>`